# How to modify this table

Tags: tables

I have this script:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs} %
\usepackage{pifont}% 
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{SSS } & \multicolumn{3}{c}{HHH} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-5}
 & & TTT \\

\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
 AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD \\

\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

I want to make it looks like:
[image]

I also want to make the colors of the horizontal lines in the second and third line to be grey. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{SSS} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{HHH} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2} \cmidrule(r){3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{TTT} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &  5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also cleaned the example to the bare minimum. Also, you load `array` and `tabularx` twice.

Comment: Thanks. How can I color the lines in the 2nd and 3rd line to grey instead of clack?

Comment: @user6875880 Code changed. Now you also get the colour change. I missed that part of the question.

Comment: After update, the code does not compile and gives: `text.tex(9): Error: Undefined control sequence. text.tex(10): Error: Misplaced \omit`.

Comment: @user6875880 Exactly this code? It runs without any problem on my system, I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure that all necessary packages are installed and up-to-date? Depending on your configuration they may not be installed on the fly if missing, or may not work together properly if some are installed in a very old version.